# send undefined in jbuilder [rails]

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, dsl

how i can produce this json with the jbuilder DSL

```
{ data: undefined }
```

I think it is necessary to precise without explaining why that
`{ data: null }`
or
`{ }`
are not the same json as the first

Comment: Why do you need to send `undefined`? Why do you need to use it instead of `null`?

Comment: Sometimes, in JS librairie, undefined and no value doesn't mean the same thing, But the problem is quite easily bypassed in effects, my curiosity makes me ask myself this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [ECMA-404 The JSON Data Interchange Standard](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-404_2nd_edition_december_2017.pdf):

> **5 JSON Values**
>
> A JSON value can be an object, array, number, string, true, false, or null
>
> [image]

It means that `undefined` is not supported by JSON

See also [JSON site](https://json.org)

In any case, sending undefined data from the backend to the frontend is quite strange. I believe that if there is such a need, it is better to use `null` value or even not send anything

Comment: Thank you for the clear and precise answer.